# Arel returning count column as string instead of int

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have three models: `Video`, `Tag`, and `Tagging`. Tags have many videos through taggings.

I have successfully added a scope to Tag that includes the video count for each tag as an extra attribute on the returned records:

```
class Tag
  def self.include_video_count
    t = Tag.arel_table
    v = Video.arel_table
    joins(:videos).select([t[Arel.star], v[:id].count.as("video_count")]).group(t[:id])
  end
end

Tag.include_video_count.first.video_count
# => "42"
```

The problem is that the count attribute is being returned as a string instead of an integer.

Is there some Arel method I am missing that specifies what type the value should be returned as?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it depends on the type of the column that the database returns (which makes sense!)

Postgres for example returns the count as a string.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3647

So... basically.. you're outa luck (as am I ;)